# Will I be worth more (salary) to my boss after completing a workshop he initiated?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I am currently doing a workshop where I am learning more about a certain tool, which is the primary tool I will be using. I am learning more about the tool, thus I am able to work better with it and create better and faster results.

This workshop was initiated and paid for by my boss so that I am able to get results more quickly rather than using hours of my boss's time to learn  the tool and still not knowing everything I will learn in the workshop.

**Can I use a completed workshop my boss initiated as leverage for a higher salary / more benefits?**

Edit:

Some additional information, I tried to keep the question too general perhaps so it could be applied too more people.

Currently I am being 'underpaid' by 500 euro bruto for the average of my study and about 800 euro for this field. But I don't feel like I am being underpaid and appreciate the oppurtunity in the field. Ofcourse I would be happy if I could make more.

My current contract is a trial period to see if things are working out between me and the bussiness, as I am doing something new for this business.

Things have worked out as I am doing the course and my boss is happy with the results I am getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is impossible to know or answer.

Comment: I think it might be better to wait and see if there are answers that are good.  Looks like we have 2 decent answers already so it seems quite possible to answer.  Even if it is impossible or just incredibly difficult to answer that does not make it off topic.

Comment: How your boss will feel (the question in the title) isn't answerable; we can't read his mind.  Whether you can leverage this is technically answerable but IMO weak; it seems like what you really want to ask is not "can I use this?" but "*how* can I use this?".  If that's the case, I suggest editing to clarify (remember to edit the title too).  Thanks.

Comment: As a boss, I'd be pretty annoyed if I paid to train someone and they then immediately asked me for a raise, citing that they were trained now.

Comment: @MGOwen: LOL! That's a great point!

Comment: You need the tool to do your job.  Your not going to get paid more money to learn the tool that allows you to do your job. This is called on the job training.  Its unlikely boss would appreciate you asking for a raise weeks after a training course.  If you were already an expert and perhaps you were doing the training yourself, thats a different story.

Comment: @MGOwen - Would you be less annoyed if you paid for someone's training and then have them go work for someone else because you don't offer a competitive wage?

Comment: @JeffO No, just as annoyed. If I help someone - even if the help also benefits me - I think it's not unreasonable to feel a bit betrayed when they throw it back in my face by using it against me. Perhaps if Ajaxkevi worked for me for a while after I trained him to at least compensate me a little, I'd be happy to give him a raise...

Comment: @MGOwen That's actually a pretty good answer! Thanks for that insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without knowing the money you now make, the money that position normally makes, and the qualifications that position has, it is impossible to know this. The mere fact of being sent on course means nothing. For example:

- perhaps people who can X make Y more than people who can't, and going on this course will make you into a person who can do X. In this case, yes, you will be in line for a raise, either when you ask for it or at your next review.
- perhaps being able to X is vital for this job, to the extent you will be fired if you can't do it, and your boss either thought you already could or was expecting you to pick it up on the job. Having to pay to send you on the workshop is a negative and asking for a raise upon gaining the skills you were supposed to already have might go over very badly.
- perhaps this skill is just one you need in general (eg communications skills, technical drawing, etc) and you are being sent to help you feel valued but it will have no involvement in your salary determinations.

It's possible you can work out which of these situations applies. The most efficient way of doing so is simply to ask your boss. You could have done so when agreeing to go on the course:

> Yes, I think that training would make me more effective. Thanks for arranging (or allowing, or suggesting) it! [tone of voice to indicate an aside or a change of subject] Will it also make me eligible for a raise?

Since you didn't ask before you go, you can do so on your return to the office:

> Thanks again for sending me on that training! I will definitely be faster now. Does this put me on a good track for a promotion soon?

Comment: I prefer the track of asking for the promotion consideration after as it says I'm willing to do what you need of me and looking to grow.  As opposed to so you spent this investment on training me now I want you to pay more money because I have the skills to do the job better though haven't shown any improvement yet.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use a completed workshop, my boss initiated, as leverage for a
>   higher salary/ more benefits?

You can certainly try, but it's not possible for anyone other than your boss to know if this will be effective.

It's possible that completion of this workshop puts you at the minimum requirements for being effective in your job. If that's the case, then you probably wouldn't be rewarded for completing the workshop - you'll just be allowed to keep your job.

It's possible that completion of the workshop is just a "nice to have". And other than adding to your stockpile of goodwill with your boss, won't have any direct effect on your compensation level.

It's possible that completion of this workshop will put you over the top of your level in your abilities, and will increase your efficiency so much that you are worth a lot more to the company. That may result in increased compensation either immediately, or somewhere down the line.

The key to determining the actual possibility is to talk with your boss.

Comment: And even if the workshop will make you more effective, he probably won't give you a salary increase until you show that you actually are more effective. Plenty of people take training and forget what they learned as soon as they leave the classroom.